# Angular : ng-if with dictionaries

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Kind new to AngularJS I'm encountering the following problem :

How could eval with `ng-if` if a dictionary is empty or not ?

With arrays `ng-if="myArray.length"` works great but doesn't with dictionaries.

Edit : Also already tried `Object.keys(myDict).length` which doesn't work.

Comment: what is a "dictionary" in javascript? a JSON object  you mean?

Comment: An associative array.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Javascript does not have associatve arrays. I think you are either referring to an object. Can you post this "associatve array" you are referring to?

Comment: `{'key':'val1', 'key2' : 'val2'}` What's that then ?

Comment: that is a JSON Object.

Comment: Come on, that's the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-if is also able to evaluate a function in scope.

For example:

```
<div ng-if="functionHere(x)" ></div>
```

Then in your controller, you could have

```
$scope.functionHere = function(input) { if [logic here]..... }
```

So, if you could contain your logic in a javascript function, then you could delegate the ng-if's decision to what the function returns.

[JSFiiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JuS7W/)

Comment: How do you know this is the answer. If the problem is not clear?

Comment: It appears as if @matthieuriegler is trying to work with Associative Arrays. Nested values tent to get messy when done in the Angular markup, so I though that I would recommend delegating that logic to a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope function:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-if="!isEmptyObject(myObj)">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isEmptyObject = function(obj) {
        for(var prop in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    $scope.myObj = {};

}]);
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/626C4/1/)